# How to rotate a square in processing?

Tags: animation, math, rotation, drawing, processing

I've been trying to rotate a square for a project, I've done research and think I have the right formula to calculate the rotated points. I calculate the points as if they're individual around the center of the square. How to fix it?

```
//Declaring variables
float x0, y0, xo, yo,x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3, theta, newx, newy, s, c;
void setup() {
size (800,800);
//To debug 
//frameRate(1);
fill(0);
//Initializing variables
xo = 400;
yo = 400;
x0 = 350;
y0 = 450;
x1 = 350;
y1 = 350;
x2 = 450;
y2 = 350;
x3 = 450;
y3 = 450;
theta = radians(5);
s = sin(theta);
c = cos(theta);
}
void draw() {
//Reseting the background
background(255);
//Drawing the square
quad(x0,y0,x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3);
//Doing the rotations
x0 = rotateX(x0,y0);
y0 = rotateY(x0,y0);
x1 = rotateX(x1,y1);
y1 = rotateY(x1,y1);
x2 = rotateX(x2,y2);
y2 = rotateY(x2,y2);
x3 = rotateX(x3,y3);
y3 = rotateY(x3,y3);
}
//Rotate x coordinate method
float rotateX(float x, float y) {
x -= xo;
newx = x * c - y * s;
x = newx + xo;
return x;
}
//Rotate y coordinate method
float rotateY(float x, float y) {
y -= yo;
newy = x * s - y * c;
y = newy + yo;
return y;
}
```

Comment: You need to clarify a bit more. You think you have the right formula, so what happened when you implemented it? What was your expected behavior? What error did you get?

Comment: When I run it, the first frame is the square at the center of the screen, the second frame is the square translated left and with all the points at random angles making the square more of a parallelogram, the third frame is the square translated further right but it's a regular square again, then it alternates between the parallelogram and square until it's off of the screen

Comment: Another thing, is that when it is just one ellipse rotating around another ellipse, the method works fine. So I'm pretty sure it's not the method or the formula in it that are wrong, it's my implementation from two points to the square.

Comment: Wait a minute the ellipse rotating around the ellipse doesn't work anymore I think I did mess the formula up or something

Comment: Please try to properly format your code. I've removed the `<code>` blocks (just use the code button from now on), but you should still fix your indentation.

Comment: Yeah I had a bit of trouble with that. I'm new to posing code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things:

1) You have a sign error in `rotateY()`. The `y` term should have a positive sign:

```
newy = x * s + y * c;
```

2) When you do this:

```
x0 = rotateX(x0,y0);
y0 = rotateY(x0,y0);
```

... then the first call modifies `x0`, which the second call then uses. But the second call needs the original coordinates to rotate correctly:

```
float x0Rotated = rotateX(x0, y0);
y0 = rotateY(x0, y0);
x0 = x0Rotated;
```

The same thing for the other points.

Comment: Thank you so much!